# VB6 code not running on other machines with "Error in loading DLL" error

Tags: vb6

I modified my vb6 project to support unicode by using **CyberActiveX UniListView100** (UniListView.ocx) controller. I updated my listview with uniListview and project is working well on my machine. But when I try to run it on another machine, it is giving '**Error in Loading DLL**' error right after I click on the 'Step into' or 'Start' button.

Once I tried with **VB Common Controls Replacement 1.4 Library** and the similar scenario happened there as well, code is only running on the machine where it created. But all machines I tried to run this code are equally set-up.

What can be the cause of this error? I even have registered the UniListView.ocx file in the Windows/SysWOW64 folder.

I tried to identified what is happening here with **Microsoft Process Monitor**, but I was unable to find anything from its logs yet.

Please tell me what can be the cause for this..

Comment: Try registering the ocx in the application's folder.

Comment: Tried, but not working.

Answer (score 3):

Often, the DLL in question is a dependency of the DLL you're trying to load. Find and use the Depends utility to see who requires what. You run Depends, Depends runs your process. First run it on your machine, then on a failing machine. The differences are usually obvious.

Comment: I heard that Dependency Walker is dead and never caught up with 64-bit modules. I tried running it on my Windows10 machine, and I can't even open any file (exe, dll, .ocx) using it.